# Tables joined without common fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server Database which has 2 tables

Client Table

```
Name    Employment Race
Ronald  867         452
Arnold  845         123
```

---

Lookup Table

```
lookup_id    Detail
867         Unemployed
845         Part time employed
452         White
123         Black
```

The numeric entries point to the primary key of LookUp table called lookup_id. Corresponding to each lookup_id (867,856 etc.) is the actual Employment or Race description in text - Unemployed, White etc. More Client fields follow the same referencing.

However, the lookup_id field by itself does not exist in the Client table. It seems to me that the two tables are linked without a PK,FK reference. Is this possible? Passing a key entry directly into a field to join tables? How do I query these tables together?

Comment: Huh? Looks to me like the missing column is right there...named Employment.

Comment: Edited: Multiple Client fields have numeric references to lookup id

Comment: I think the problem here is that sometimes people get hung up about joins and think there has to be a foreign key established for the join to work. Thankfully this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via a query like this.

**new query:**

```
SELECT Name, L1.Detail AS Employment, L2.Detail as Race
FROM Client C LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup L1
    ON C.Employment=L1.lookup_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup L2
    ON C.Race=L2.lookup_id
```

**old query:**

```
SELECT Name, Detail 
FROM Client C LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup L
 ON C.Employment=L.lookup_id
```

A FK need not have same name as PK in the FK table, like here Employment and Race columns are foreign key value for `Lookup`.

Also you should but not necessarily have a FK PK relation defined between tables. This is a common practice in Data warehousing.